# AngularJS - Access grand parent variable

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

The state controller has the following variable:

```
vm.stateControllerVariable = 1;
```

The state template has the following directive:

```
<div directive-aleluia></div>
```

The directive-aleluia template:

```
<div directive-arebaba></div>
```

The directive-arebaba template:

```
<span>{{ vm.stateControllerVariable }}</span>
<!-- How can I show the grand parent controller variable here? -->
```

Answer (score 0):

To inherit data from parent scope, the directive cannot have an isolated scope, the value of the 2 directives have to be true or false.

If you need an isolated scope from your directive, you should pass

> vm.stateControllerVariable

as parameter in your isolated scope.

See [explaination about directive](https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

Just pass the grandparent (controller) variable into the isolated scope in child and grandchild directives

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.stateControllerVariable = 'Hello State';
    });

    app.directive('directiveAleluia', function(){
      return {
        scope: {
          someVar: '='
        },
        template: '<div directive-arebaba some-var="someVar"></div>'
      };
    });

    app.directive('directiveArebaba', function(){
      return {
        scope: {
          someVar: '='
        },
        template: '<span>{{ someVar }}</span>'
      };
    });
```

> HTML

```
<div directive-aleluia some-var="stateControllerVariable"></div>
```

> Working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/HZwD3sQZ5kJUAoFRujbW?p=preview